# #define ABS(x) ((x >= 0) ? x : -x) C# Unity3D Giving error: "Cannot define or undefine preprocessor symbols after first token in file"

Tags: c#, c-preprocessor

I don't know if this is a C# question, or specifically Unity3d's implementation:

Where should this normally be placed:

```
#define ABS(x) ((x >= 0) ? x : -x)
```

I'm getting "Cannot define or undefine preprocessor symbols after first token in file" wherever I try. e.g

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
#define ABS(x) ((x >= 0) ? x : -x)

public class FillTriangle {
…
}
```

Should this work in standard MSDN C#?

Comment: In C#.Net they must appear at the very top of the source file and do not allow the definition of macros (only symbols)

Comment: Furthermore, there's no need to define macros like that in C# because short functions will be automatically inlined in release builds (if possible).

Comment: Thanks. No macros??? Converting C code… there goes my lunch break. (In that example I know I can find/replace with Math.Abs(), but for old custom macros it's a PIA)

Comment: @Raymond Chen I can tell you that because I did not have prior knowledge of how they work, that would *not* have made it any clearer.

Comment: If all else fails, [read the documentation](http://www.jaggersoft.com/csharp_standard/9.5.3.htm). A language works the way it is specified, not the way you wish it worked.

Comment: See Alex K's comment on how to be helpful here.